# How to create keycloak backups when using the helm chart

Tags: backup, keycloak, kubernetes-helm

I have set up a keycloak-cluster by using the helm chart. Everything works fine so far. However, I need to create backups for disaster recovery cases.

My environment:

- Keycloak cluster with 2 instances
- Deployed with the helm chart

  - So, keycloak is running in containers in kubernetes pods
- External database (postgres)

Unfortunately, neither the readme in the [helm chart github repo](https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/keycloak), nor the [Server Administration guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/) provide a description how to create backups correctly.

The section `Import/Export` in the guide describes how to export the data, but it mentions to execute `standalone.sh`, which seems not practical in a clustered- and containerized enviroment (connect to the containers, and execute it in there?). So it seems practical for one time migation, but not for a recurring backup.

An entry in the [mailinglist](https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2018-February/013006.html) indicates, that a backup of the Database should be sufficient, but after someone asked if this is all that is necessary, no answer was provided yet.

So my question is:

#### Is it sufficient to create a backup of the database in order to get reliable backups with all the data? (users, realms ...)

I've asked a similar question in the [keycloak helm repository](https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/issues/351), but maybe someone here knows a solution.

If additional information for an answer is required, please let me know!

Comment: for configuration backup, you can use JSON import/export however keycloack stores user data in the database at the end yes just DB backup will work.